# Text-Align sub item in Wordpress CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm practing with Wordpress and CSS but it's not working out for me. I'm trying to put the link/text exactly in the center but somehow it doesn't work for me. If I add padding or margin he will add some weird space there.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtZ3X.png)

I want to have Test 1, test 2 etc centered within that menu. Please see below the code I currently have:

```
    /* Navigatie */
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: url(http://localhost/blog/images/nav.jpg);
    display: block;
    float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: white;
}

/* Muis hover linkjes */
.main-navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Kleur na visited */
.main-navigation a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  text-align: center;
}



.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}


.main-navigation ul ul a {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<title>TESTEAMS &#8211; En nog een WordPress site</title>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="TESTEAMS &raquo; Feed" href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="TESTEAMS &raquo; Reactiesfeed" href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost\/blog\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.2"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var b,c,d,e,f=String.fromCharCode;if(!k||!k.fillText)return!1;switch(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.textBaseline="top",k.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return k.fillText(f(55356,56826,55356,56819),0,0),!(j.toDataURL().length<3e3)&&(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,65039,8205,55356,57096),0,0),b=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,55356,57096),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),b!==c);case"emoji4":return k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,8205,55357,56507),0,0),d=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,55357,56507),0,0),e=j.toDataURL(),d!==e}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i,j=b.createElement("canvas"),k=j.getContext&&j.getContext("2d");for(i=Array("flag","emoji4"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mindset-style-css'  href='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/mindset-child/style.css?ver=4.7.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://localhost/blog/index.php/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/blog/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.7.2" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/blog/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://localhost/blog/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fblog%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fblog%2F&#038;format=xml" />
    <style type="text/css">
            .site-title,
        .site-description {
            position: absolute;
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        }
        </style>
    </head>

<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-78">
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
                            <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/blog/" rel="home">TESTEAMS</a></p>
                            <p class="site-description">En nog een WordPress site</p>
                    </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
            <div class="menu-hoofdnavigatie-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/home/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/berichten/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-71"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/mlm-bedrijven/">MLM Bedrijven</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/mlm-bedrijven/x/">X</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/mlm-bedrijven/v/">V</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-62"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/factsheets/">Factsheets</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/wie-zijn-wij/">Wie zijn wij</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-55"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/contact/">Contact</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/contact/test-1/">Test 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/contact/test-2/">Test 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://localhost/blog/index.php/contact/test-3/">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


<article id="post-78" class="post-78 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Dit is dé plek voor entrepreneurs</h1>  </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website. Dit is de voorpagina van de website.</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </article><!-- #post-## -->

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->


    </div><!-- #content -->

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
            &copy Domein.nl | Onderdeel van QEAMS
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/mindset/js/navigation.js?ver=20151215'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-content/themes/mindset/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20151215'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/blog/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your html too

Comment: As I mentioned, it's Wordpress.

Comment: You can still share the generated HTML

Comment: but wordpress give you html output you can see on inspect element

Comment: I edited my post with the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey understand I created a simple basic example to understand here you are

```css
/* Navigatie */

.main-navigation {
  background: blue;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/* Muis hover linkjes */

.main-navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: red;
}


/* Kleur na visited */

.main-navigation a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
</ul>
```